# how to create/call/close independent python processes

Tags: python, linux, sockets, subprocess, fork

i am new to Python - and listed below a few, perhaps trivial, questions.  i work on Slackware Linux with Python 3.4.3.

i need to start a python program A that sticks around so one can call it periodically via a UNIX shell or a webbrowser and direct its output to either of them.  i phrased below several questions at once because they all seem to me related in this project (which may run at some point also on OS-X, perhaps even on windows).

1) how do i fork/spawn this python process A so it becomes independent of shells (python or terminal) and stays there in RAM memory to follow commands till told to close itself ?  by using subprocess.Popen for a new process B ?  by running a daemon ?

2) how do i locate this python process A (or B) through its PID ?  by using psutils and a PID lock or logfile ?

3) how do i call this process A (or B) from a Python shell or a UNIX shell or a webbrowser ?  by using socket.socket and PID ?

4) how do i direct the output of this process A (or B) to a shell or to a webbrowser ?  writing to a file seems simple.  MVC for the latter - or can we keep it simple à la KISS ?

many thanks in advance, bye, pisti

Comment: It looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/137096).  What is the context? If you are sure that these are the questions you want to be answered then ask each *"how do I...?"* as a separate SO question.

Answer (score 0):

Your question already contains the answer: create a daemon that listens for commands and you could access it using a socket.

In many cases, your service does not need to daemonize itself (using [`python-daemon` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/)), a supervisor program that you use for deployment does it instead (such as [`supervisord`](http://supervisord.org/) or [`circus`](http://circus.readthedocs.org/)).

There are frameworks such as [`Eve`](http://python-eve.org/) that make it very easy to create web-accessible api in Python (you can consume it from the shell using `curl`).

Comment: thanks much for your input - these are all new techniques i will look into. especially Eve is newland to me.